# Difference between tables created in SQL DataWarehouse and Database

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse

I know it sounds very silly question but I want to know in what way the tables and their properties would differ if it is created in data warehouse and database.

Answer (score 3):

So data warehouse is an another way to store data but it remains a database.

```
DATABASE: Any collection of data organized for storage, accessibility, and retrieval.   
DATA WAREHOUSE: A type of database that integrates copies of transaction data from disparate source systems and provisions them for analytical use.
```

The main differences are on high level schema, but at low level they're both databases.

For a more deep explanation: https://www.differencebtw.com/difference-between-database-and-data-warehouse/